# Sick leopard gecko declining rapidly - Mouth Rot, irritated skin etc

Tags: health, leopard-geckos

We have a very ill leopard gecko and we would really appreciate if anyone with experience with leos could share some thoughts/help/guidance.

It's a long story so strap in.

**December**

Around mid-December we discovered that our leopard gecko had, what appeared to be at the time, something 'stuck' under her left 'lip'.

We took her to the Herp vet who informed us it was pus from the start of a mouth rot infection. Since it appeared only minor, they removed and treated it and we were told to treat the mouth area for the next few days with a diluted solution of iodine.

**January**

Mid-January - A second appearance of mouth rot but this time on the right side of her mouth. We removed the pus ourselves this time and continued with the iodine treatment.

**February**

28 Feb - There was a re-appearance of mouth rot on the left side. We took her back to the vet who prescribed a 3-week course of antibiotics via injection.

**March**

21 March - Gave her the last injection. We had to leave for a family holiday and left her in the care of a reputable reptile 'pet hotel'.

**April**

7 April - We returned from our holiday and picked her up from the pet hotel. We noticed a difference in her behaviour and her tail was a bit thinner. No signs of mouth rot. Her appetite wasn't amazing and the pet hotel informed us that she wasn't eating that well during her stay.

23 April - Back to the vet as the mouth rot returned and was pretty bad this time. Vet prescribed second course of antibiotics.

**May**

6 May - Infection flared up for the fifth time. Continued with antibiotics.

8/9 May - Over these two days we noticed her left her was a bit closed and then both eyes were closed. She hasn't been able to open them since. We're using vet prescribed eye drops to prevent infection.

11 May - Last injection of the antibiotic.

14 May - Back to the vet for a follow up appointment. During this visit they informed us that the mouth rot infection had cleared up pretty well but an infection had spread to her throat (hence why she wasn't eating). The sides of her throat were enlarged.

During this visit, they noticed her liver was swollen. They tried to take blood from her tail for tests but unfortunately during this attempt she dropped her tail.

Vet prescribed a different course of antibiotics.

We also have been trying to feed her vet prescribed cat food thats very liquid with vitamin A. She's had very little of this.

20 May - We noticed a weird patch on her back which over a few hours looked very raw and burn-like.

22 May - Took her to the vet for help with the injection. More of her skin has become red, looks sore and started peeling off when they picked her up. She's very lethargic and doesn't move around much but drinks a lot of water.

The vet thought it was Vitamin A toxicity because of the dry, burn-like nature of the skin but said this only happened from vitamin A injections and shouldn't be caused from the Vitamin A supplement we lightly dusted with the cat food.

**General notes:**

- She has the appropriate terrarium with heating at the right temperature (27˚C on the heat mat side, 21˚C on the cool side).
- Appropriate lighting with day/night cycles.
- She had two hidey-holes, one humid.
- Water bowl.
- Terrarium felt lines the bottom.
- It gets cleaned regularly and disinfected.
- Food supplier has never changed and worms are gut loaded.

We're not sure what's wrong with her or why she's declined so rapidly. We've obviously sought professional help throughout this process and are at a loss.

Our leo is very dear to us and want her to recover. We'd appreciate if anyone can share knowledge or experience with us that can help.